Check if system time was changed before opening an application using .net
I am making a C# app, where I want to know if system time was changed by the user before opening the app. When the app is running, I am planning to use the SystemEvents.TimeChanged event. But I do not know how to see if user has changed the application before opening the application.
I have tried googling, but was not able to get the required answer. Majority of the answers are for C/Cpp.
Edit:
The problem I am facing is as follows:
The C# WPF application I am working on is a license-based application. We are using an Expiry datetime in our license, after which the tool will stop working.
I am using the DateTime.Now to fetch the current datetime, check if it has exceeded the Expiry datetime, and determine if I close the tool. We are using UTC time(converted to local time before comparison with DateTime.Now) for the Expiry datetime.
I wanted to know how I can identify whether the user of the application has changed the system time to increase the duration of the license, before starting the application.
E.g. If my license is going to expire at 10 p.m., it is 8 p.m. now, but I change the system time to 2 p.m., how can this be identified?

any chance of simply using an external (and ideally signed, i.e. trusted for some definition of "trust") time server?

Check if time was changed sounds like XY problem to me. What is X problem?

As user Sinatr wrote in a comment, this is probably an X/Y problem, so instead of asking Y, please tell us what your real X issue is.  But while waiting for that, here is an answer to Y:
There is no general solution to this problem.  However, if you are running on Windows, you can look at the System Event Log for instances of system event 4616 "The system time was changed" Microsoft documentation here.
If the "Subject\Security ID" of the event is not "LOCAL SERVICE", then this event is about a time change initiated by a user.

Nice idea but presumably needs privileges to look at the event log.
